# Dynamic OG tags to facebook share button

Tags: php, html, facebook, meta-tags, meta

My website http://voteupvotedown.com/ contains a lot of images. I wants to add a FB share button to each image.It is working, but i'm facing a serious problem.When i share an image the actual image is not showing instead of that the first image from the website is showing.Is there any way to get the corresponding images when click on a share button ? I mean is there anyway to add meta OG tags Dynamically ?

Comment: _“I mean is there anyway to add meta OG tags Dynamically?”_ – of course there is, PHP can output anything you want “dynamically.” // But you need to share different URLs; you can not change the meta data for one and the same URL all the time. Or you use the Feed dialog for sharing, that still allows those values to be specified at runtime.

Comment: Yes i,m sharing different urls.and its working. But i'm get the same image for all urls.and i'm looking for a way to change that images."use the Feed dialog for sharing" I don't understand that term.

Comment: _“But i'm get the same image for all urls”_ – and do you have a different `og:image` value specified for each of those URLs?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way. You can add different ID for different photo. For example, Sachin link would be http://voteupvotedown.com/?photo=sachin and Modi link would be http://voteupvotedown.com/?photo=modi.

To get this to work, first change your php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["photo"]))
{
    if($_GET["photo"]=="sachin")
    {
        <meta property="og:image" content="path/to/sachin.png">
    }
    else if($_GET["photo"]=="modi")
    {
        <meta property="og:image" content="path/to/modi.png">
    }
}
else
{
    //Set Default Image
    <meta property="og:image" content="path/to/logo.png">
}
?>
```

And then, you need to create different share buttons with different link, but all links will share same page.